# Best way to trigger a google cloud function by an iOS app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm building out a Swift app that pulls data from MongoDB based on URLs as the primary key.  If the URL is not already in a collection, then I want to trigger a Google Cloud Function to go and check the URL and add it to the database.

While looking through Cloud Function triggering options, I didn't see a simple way to have it monitor for writes to MongoDB (the plan was to have a table of new URLs that would get run through the cloud function.)

I saw PubSub and Firebase triggers, and PubSub seemed like the best option, however I couldn't find a lot of information on publishing messages to PubSub from iOS (though plenty on subscribing)

I do see a lot of iOS documentation for FireBase.  I'm wondering if it's best to write to Firebase and trigger on that, so every user of the app, when inputting an unrecognized URL, the app would write that URL to Firebase, which would trigger a cloud function.  Or should I figure out how to have the iOS app publish a message to PubSub topic?  For now I don't need a super fast response, as the system is expected to take time to handle new URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely have a better experience writing to Firebase and having Firebase trigger your Cloud Function. There is unfortunately no officially supported Cloud Pub/Sub client in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

> Best way to trigger a google cloud function by an iOS app

From your question title and body, I  would say the the best way is to call, from you app, a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

As explained in the doc:

> The Cloud Functions for Firebase client SDKs let you call functions
> directly from a Firebase app. To call a function from your app in this
> way, write and deploy an HTTPS Callable function in Cloud Functions,
> and then add client logic to call the function from your app.

All the details on how to write the Cloud Function, as well as how to call it from your iOS app are to be found in the doc referred to above.

Comment: Thanks I'll dig into that as an alternative.  I felt that writing to a DB and triggering on that is better so that in case one of the processes die the request is still recorded.

Comment: Yes writing to DB is one alternative. Note that it adds the cost of the write to the DB compared to a Callable Cloud Function which does not incur any extra cost than the Cloud Function invocation.